# How to delete firebase child after app is deleted?

Tags: firebase, dynamic

I want to delete a child from firebase after app is deleted from phone. Is there any way to do this in android? Can I manage this flow with dynamic links?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You cannot delete child for app deletion, can you explain more what do you want achieve after deletion of child?

Comment: I thought that if user uninstalls app, his/her data should not exist in db anymore, but if app is installed again, data must in db. Other way user have to register again and it is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an opportunity to run any app code when the user uninstalls your app from their device.  If you are trying to clean up stale data, you'll have to do that yourself on a server with the Admin SDK, periodically looking for stale data (by some date that you wrote to the database), then deleting it.